# Magento Standard Registration Page 'Last Name' Field

Tags: magento

I have been working with the Registration page of Magento which comes with the standard installation.

Over there I want to make the Lastname not Mandatory. I did some investigation and found text itself is rendering from the database.

I went to Widgets/Name.phtml , try to remove the required field class. Didn't work.
Then in the EAV attribute table , attribute_Code lastname , in that row I changed the value of
is_required column from 1 to 0 . Didn't work .

it says'The last name cannot be empty'.
I want to post this empty
Could someone please help me. I went to check Javascript files as well. no luck

Comment: are you definitely sure magento isn't use `Lastname` in necessary code blocks? Don't try if you aren't sure anyhthing.

Comment: it's mandatory in magneto, but i want to make it not mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hei,

look at the customer model (customer/customer::validate) the method validate, here it validates lastname, you have to overwrite this method and remove validation of lastname.

cheers

Comment: Thanks, yes i could see the validation. But are you sure if i change that to not required that won't effect it anywhere else in the system. I mean where ever in the system customer object is used.

Comment: Your are right but i also have to change the is_required from database eav_attribute table